# Actualizar los valores de un libro del que voy a copiar info

Tags: excel, vba

tengo esta macro la cual copia la informacion de un libro a otro mediante la funcion vlookup, la macro funciona solo que a la hora de pegar los valores de un libro a otro me abre una ventana para que seleccione el libro de destino para actualizar los valores del mismo, quisiera que desde que abra el libro de destino se actualicen esos valores sin tener que preguntarme una y otra vez ya que esta funcion es para varias hojas y me pide actualizar esos valores cada vez que va a copiarlos en una nueva pagina, como resultado de no actualizarlos me muestra #N/A todo lo contrario de si los actualizos lo cual muestra el valor que estoy buscando en la funcion.

`Public Sub VLOOKUP()
Dim i As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim scheduleBook As Workbook
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If FileName = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected", , "Error"
Else
    Set scheduleBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    i = 2
    e = 1
    c = 8
Line1:
    If e < c Then
        Workbooks(1).Activate
        Sheets(e).Activate
        Sheets(e).Range("E2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],'[scheduleBook]Sheet1'!C1:C8," & i & ",false)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Select
        Selection.FillDown
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("E2").Select
        If e < 7 Then
            i = i + 1
            e = e + 1
            ActiveSheet.Next.Select
            GoTo Line1
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If
End Sub`

Si pudieran decirme una manera de que esto no se muestre y de que los valores se actualizen automaticamente seria genial, muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 1):

[VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Funci%C3%B3n-BUSCARV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?CorrelationId=766c28f4-1b5c-430a-9104-d026a6040f5f&ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES&ocmsassetID=HP010343011) es el nombre en inglés de una función incluida en Excel por lo que no se debería utilizar como nombre de una macro ni de un procedimiento.

Relacionado

- [Overriding a builtin excel function with macro or add in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4702502/1595451)
- [Reglas de nomenclatura de Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/gg264773.aspx)
- [Evitar conflictos de nombre](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/office/gg264615.aspx)